# Packing @1x, @2x, @3x versions when uploading a Flutter app to Appstore

Tags: swift, flutter, mobile

I'm developing a Flutter mobile app and planning to upload to Appstore. As I've known, in Swift, when we upload an app to Appstore, it will packs 3 versions: @1x assets, @2x assets, and @3x assets and downloads the corresponding version based on the users' device (for example, 3x-version for iPhone 13 and 2x-version for iPhone 7).

I'm wondering if there's a similar mechanism with Flutter app?

Comment: See: https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/assets-and-images#resolution-aware